# How to patch a class instance method when using an asyncio queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm trying to write a test for a class which handles a message queue which is implemented using an asyncio Queue, but I'm having difficulty patching a particular instance method in the class. Specifically, the behavior I'm seeing is that the method appears to be properly patched before a message is queued, but the patch reverts after a message is queued and the worker task begins processing it:

```
# message_queue_handler.py

import asyncio

class MessageQueueHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.worker_task = None

    def do_stuff(self,msg):
        pass

    async def start(self):
        self.worker_task = asyncio.create_task(self.worker())
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

    def queue_msg(self, msg):
        self.queue.put_nowait(msg)

    async def worker(self):
        while True:
            print(self.do_stuff)
            msg = await self.queue.get()
            print(self.do_stuff)
```

---

```
# test_message_queue_handler.py    

from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
from message_queue_handler import MessageQueueHandler

def mock_do_stuff(self,msg):
    pass

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch('message_queue_handler.MessageQueueHandler.do_stuff',new=mock_do_stuff)
async def test_patch_do_stuff():
    handler = MessageQueueHandler()
    await handler.start()
    handler.queue_msg("foo")
```

Expected output:

```
do_stuff before: <bound method mock_do_stuff of <message_queue_handler.MessageQueueHandler object at...>>
do_stuff after: <bound method mock_do_stuff of <message_queue_handler.MessageQueueHandler object at...>>
```

Actual output:

```
do_stuff before: <bound method mock_do_stuff of <message_queue_handler.MessageQueueHandler object at...>>
do_stuff after: <bound method MessageQueueHandler.do_stuff of <message_queue_handler.MessageQueueHandler object at...>>
```

Why is the patch no longer in place after the worker task gets control back?